# How to implement a FireMonkey TStringGrid Sort function: TFMXObjectSortCompare?

Tags: delphi, sorting, delphi-xe2, implementation, firemonkey

```
type
  TMyForm= class(TForm)
    sg       : TStringGrid;
    imgSortIt: TImage;
    ...
    procedure imgSortItClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
//    sortIt: TFMXObjectSortCompare;
    function sortIt(item1, item2: TFmxObject): Integer;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frm: TMyForm;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TMyForm.imgSortItClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  sg.Sort(???);
...
```

Hi,

I know how to switch rows to manually sort a grid...

But as a `TSTringGrid` has a procedure `Sort`, I try to use it with my own comparison function with [this procedure](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/fr/FMX.Types.TFmxObject.Sort)...

How should I structure the type/function to make it work?
Actually, I get:

- `E2009 Incompatible types: 'regular procedure and method pointer'`
- **or** it compiles with a function declared like this: `sortIt: TFMXObjectSortCompare;` but how to implement the code to sort like I wish?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the [XE3 documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.TFmxObjectSortCompare), according to which `TFmxObjectSortCompare` is declared as:

```
reference to function(Right, Left: TFmxObject): Integer;
```

In [XE2](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/FMX.Types.TFmxObjectSortCompare), unfortunately, `TFmxObjectSortCompare` is declared like this:

```
function(item1, item2: TFmxObject): Integer;
```

So you will need to supply a regular procedure. That is, `sortIt` is not allowed to be a method of a class and must be just a plain old function:

```
function sortIt(item1, item2: TFmxObject): Integer;
begin
  Result := ...
end;
```

I suspect that this was a design error in the XE2 FMX code. The sort compare function is much more flexible as `reference to`, which presumably is why it was changed.

Comment: Thank you for the details.
BTW, the `TFmxObject` are `TStringColumn`s... so not very usefull to sort the rows ;o) I'll do it manually...